# Copy profile to related accounts broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Reports an error with a div popup.

At least it does for my profile, on any site.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/144906?tab=accounts#tab-top

```
An error occurred during copying - please try again.
(click on this box to dismiss)
```

Comment: Do you happen to have the text of the error you're getting?

Comment: @wai - there ya go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with datatype mismatches between the Q&A sites and Area51.

Because we now allow markdown support in the "About Me" section, we had to increase the column size to accommodate the "renderable" html.  This column size increase wasn't deployed on Area51.

A fix will be deployed tomorrow or Monday.

Comment: 4k works for me.