# Error when trying to copy SO profile to other sites

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

Every time I try to copy my SO profile to other sites I get the error message

> An error occurred during copying - please try again.
>   (click on this box to dismiss)

and apparently no profile gets synced. [This bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61054/copy-profile-to-related-accounts-broken) sounds identical, but since it's already resolved, it seems to have a different cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al, your username must be at least 3 characters.

You are grandfathered in for some areas of the network, but you won't be able to copy a 2 character name anywhere else.

Comment: I'm a grandfather - That happened faster than I expected.